# **TypeError: can't pickle tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Operation objects**

Tags: pickle, machine-translation, tensorflow-addons

I am using Tensorflow-addons API for a machine translation project.

I want to load my models and do predictions without train them again.

My architecture is Encoder - Decoder with Bahdanau Attention mechanism.

When I try to serialize, with **dill** module,  the encoder and decoder objects in a file and  I get this error :

**TypeError: can't pickle tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session.TF_Operation objects**

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: I am having the same problem, but in my case im trying to save a custom loss function to load my model later.